# What tense to use?

Tags: grammar

What tense should I use in post-reading questions if the author himself uses both Present Simple and Past Simple when telling this story? Thank you!

Comment: Can you quote some parts of the story and what you want to say? That can help us determine what tense we should use.

Comment: @OmegaKrypton I knew there was something wrong. Cause as soon as I stepped foot into the house, my cousin starts laughing. My cousin cut my hair for 25 minutes. And all of the sudden he stops.

Comment: Thanks. And what you are going to write?

Comment: @OmegaKrypton I need to ask questions about the content of the story, like Why did he do that/why did he suddenly stop and so on but I’m just not sure what tense to use

Comment: Then past tense like that in your comment! refer to fact part in commentary (my answer)

Answer (score 0):

@viewers, please tell me if I'm wrong. Thank you!

For me, regardless of the tense the story is written in, I usually write the summary/facts in Present Tense. And for the commentary/opinions, I usually use the Present tense for my feelings, and Past when referring to the events in the book/ story.

Hope it helps!